# Where will be the source code to parse DTB file in kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, device-tree

I wanna know where the parsing of device tree will happen in linux kernel? I mean where can i find the kernel source code to parse all device tree info, all nodes?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the parser code [here](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.15-rc9/source/lib), CONFIG_LIBFDT is config which builds it so look for the Makefile in lib directory, which builds libfdt_files.